Creating JOOQ objects during the Docker image build process using a PostgreSQL container
I'm working on a side project and I want to create a docker-compose in order to deploy the project locally successfully.
The main flow is:

Deploy a PostgresSQL container with init.sql file
Generate JOOQ code for application (in image build phase)
Copy the generated code to the image and run app

However, no matter what I do, the container I'm trying to build cannot connect to the PostgresSQL container and generate the code.
I've tried using links, networks and nothing seems to work.
Docker Compose:
services:
  database:
    container_name: database
    hostname: database
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - PGUSER=user
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d $${POSTGRES_DB} -U $${POSTGRES_USER}" ]
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks: 
      -mynet

  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      -mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge

Dockerfile:
FROM maven:3.9.7-amazoncorretto-17 AS build
COPY models models

RUN mvn clean package -f models/pom.xml -Plocal

pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.abl.rjmdb</groupId>
    <artifactId>models</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jooq.version>3.19.8</jooq.version>
        <postgresql.version>42.7.3</postgresql.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                <database.driver>org.postgresql.Driver</database.driver>
                <database.url>jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/db</database.url>
                <database.user>user</database.user>
                <database.password>password</database.password>
                <database.schema>public</database.schema>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                        <version>${jooq.version}</version>

                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>

                        <configuration>
                            <jdbc>
                                <driver>${database.driver}</driver>
                                <url>${database.url}</url>
                                <user>${database.user}</user>
                                <password>${database.password}</password>
                            </jdbc>
                            <generator>
                                <database>
                                    <includes>.*</includes>
                                    <inputSchema>${database.schema}</inputSchema>
                                </database>
                                <target>
                                    <packageName>com.abl.rjmdb.model.jooq</packageName>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                                </target>
                            </generator>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>

The error I get:
if I use "database" host -

11.96 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.19.8:generate (default) on project models: Error running jOOQ code generation tool: The connection attempt failed. Unknown host database -> [Help 1]

if I use "127.0.0.1" host -

Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.19.8:generate (default) on project models: Error running jOOQ code generation tool: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. Connection refused

if I use the IP address I got from docker inspect <container name>:

Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.19.8:generate (default) on project models: Error running jOOQ code generation tool: Connection to 172.17.0.2:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. Connection refused

Any ideas how I can approach this?
I've checked countless times, the PostgresSQL container runs and I can connect to it from the host.
Maybe it is not a good practice to generate JOOQ code inside a docker image?
I'm attaching the repository in case it is somehow relevant: https://github.com/AmitBarlev/RJMDB

Correct, an image build can never connect to another container.  Can you generate the model objects in another context and check them into your repository, so you don't need an external database running just to build a jar file?

Why not use this testcontainers approach here? https://blog.jooq.org/using-testcontainers-to-generate-jooq-code/
